# SQL AVG cant get to work

Tags: sql, average

I am having trouble displaying the average age alongside other data, i know it should display more then one field but it only displays one field.

```
SELECT EmpName, Age,AVG(Age)
FROM   Employee
WHERE  Age > ( SELECT AVG(Age)
               FROM   Employee
             )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT EmpName, Age, (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM Employee) AverageAge
FROM Employee
WHERE Age > (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM Employee);
```

here is the right code , i think u can't use AVG(Age) next to SELECT cause it's not an exist column.

Comment: Well, you just dropped the average. But it can still be included, by repeating the nested select.

Comment: Where do i repeat the nested select can you give an example?

Comment: @user3676186: By copying the select part to the select line.

Comment: @Muhab: I altered your code. Hope you are fine with it. If not, just rollback my change.

Comment: @PatrickHofman is it better if `AVG(Age)` is assigned to a variable and use variable in `select`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: If you are lucky, the optimizer does this for you. If not, yes, moving it (like I did) is better for performance. You could do a CTE if necessary, it makes sure it really runs once.

Comment: this code produces two tables, the second one is correct but the first one is not

Comment: @PatrickHofman `If you are lucky`!!! Why optimizer don't have a fixed strategy to evaluate?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: It has. But there are a million ways to run a query, and the optimizer tries to help you make it perform (by creating the fastest way to do something), but it is never perfect, so we should think about it first.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it's fine , i have benefited with your edit too ;)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the line *and* get the overall average. Try to join them:

```
SELECT e.EmpName
,      e.Age
,      a.AverageAge
FROM   Employee e
CROSS
JOIN   ( SELECT AVG(Age) AverageAge
         FROM   Employee
       ) a
WHERE  Age > AverageAge
```

Comment: The `on` clause does not have to be there. Joins are fine without it.

Comment: Join `ON 1=1` is called a `CROSS JOIN` (which has no `ON` clause)

Comment: Thanks guys. Old habit. Updated the code. Didn't know if every platform supports it.

Comment: is there any simpler way to do this, i do not understand what is happening here

Comment: It just moves the selection to an 'inline view' (here called `a`) so you can query the results later. What you were trying is not possible. This is as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HAVING clause to achieve it

```
select name,age,avg(age)
from emp
group by name,age
having age > (select avg(age) from emp)
```

Comment: `avg(age)` in `select` won't show average of all `age`, but only which satisfy the `Group` clause.